# jQuery debug functionlity in a "class" file

Tags: javascript, jquery

im creating a simple game and, I need some direction for debuging some data.
i have a div in my HTML file, that I want him to show some data that change when some variables get change by the user actions.

for exmple i got `var xPosition`, I want to send the data to a div in the HTML, so i can see the current state of `xPosition`.

i realy dont have any idea where to start creating this functionlity.

**my questions:**

1. is it possible to create event inside this class and register some
       element to him  that will show all the changing data?
2. do i have to use a some a timer for that sort of thing?

this is the "class":

```
(function ($) {
    $.Player = function (element) {
        this.element = (element instanceof $) ? element : $(element);
        this.movmentSpeed = 10;
        this.size = $(element).width();
        this.xPos = 0;
        this.yPos = 0;
    };


    $.Player.prototype = {
        //register events
        InitEvents: function () {
            var that = this;
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                var key = e.which;
                if (key == 39) {
                    that.moveRight(400);
                } else if (key == 37) {
                    that.moveLeft();
                }
            });

            this.element.css({
                left: this.xPos
            });
        },

        //movment functions
        moveRight: function (worldWidth) {
            if ((this.xPos + this.size) <= worldWidth) {
                this.xPos += this.movmentSpeed;
                this.element.css("left", '+=' + this.movmentSpeed);
            }
        },
        moveLeft: function () {
            if (this.xPos > 0) {
                this.xPos -= this.movmentSpeed;
                this.element.css("left", '-=' + this.movmentSpeed);
            }
        }
    };

} (jQuery));
```

here the HTML:

```
<div id="player">
<div id="debugData"> <div>
<script>
var player = new $.Player($("#player"));
        player.InitEvents();

</script>
```

(sorry for my english)

Comment: You could write setters to change the variables you're interested in. That way you can log whatever you need in real time :)

Comment: is an idea, but i realy want to do that on HTML for 2 resons. 1. is much easier to read 2. i want to learn how to do this :)

Comment: By logging I meant appending to your debug div.

Comment: intresting, i didnt know you can do that. (if is not so hard) can you show me a simple code example?

Comment: Search for jQuery append :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rQAKU/)**

I'd say having an internal function inside the Class would help.  Maybe even having a setting where you turn the logging on by doing `player.logging = true;`, and having it default to false;

In your prototype just add a public prototype variable for `logging = false`, and our prototype function `log()`.

The internal function you could use could be something as simple as:

```
    logging : false, // our default

    log : function (str) {
        if (this.logging) {
            $('#debugData').html(str);
        }
    },
```

This way you could **leave** your `log(this.xPos);` (or whatever you want to log) within your code, and by removing the `player.logging = true;` when you instantiate your class, they won't show up, till you put that code back in.

Comment: this give me the behiover i want, but im not sure where to put it in the my class. i want to keep the function private as you suggested but doing that it dosnt let me use the class (this) variables inside this function. where should i put it so i can see log private variable and also public? (thanks for help :) )

Comment: Updated the answer with a demo also! Hope that clears things up

Comment: i fix that in a similier way but yours is much better! Thank you!!